# Why is the RX and TX values ​the same when executing the network packet statistics script on centos8?

Tags: shell

##test1 on rhel8 or centos8

`$for i in 1 2;do cat /proc/net/dev | grep ens192 | awk '{print "RX:"$2"\n""TX:"$10}';done | awk '{print $0}' | tee 111`

##result:
RX:2541598118
TX:1829843233
RX:2541598118
TX:1829843233

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I believe your post would be a better match for [Unix/Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Anyways RX and TX are the counts of received and transmitted packets respectively.

Comment: because there was no network traffic between first and second time you read `/proc/net/dev`

Comment: `awk '{print $0}' |` does nothing useful

Comment: I know "awk '{print $0}'" useless but it doesn't affect the result display, so I didn't delete it